# Avoid pagebreak in one table row while printing

Tags: php, css, row, css-tables, page-break

I create some PHP script, which is called to print. But, unfortunately I have a small problem..

You can see the problem in photo:

[image: HERE]

I need to secure this pagebreak, when text in first TD is on last page and pictures in second and third TD are in new page.

I tried to use

> page-break-inside: avoid !important;

than

> white-space: nowrap;

... but nothink help

here is my table CSS.

```
table.prvni {
        margin: 100px 10px 0px 10px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
  caption {
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    th:first-child {
        width: 250px;
        padding: 3px 6px;
    }

    th:last-child {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 3px 3px;
    }

    th {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 3px 6px;
    }

    tr:first-child {
        background: #ecefef;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    tr {
        background: #f7fafa;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    td:first-child {
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    td:last-child {
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    td {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Can anybody  help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just change CSS, important are page-break parameters.

```
 table.prvni {
   margin: 100px 10px 0px 10px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   page-break-inside:auto;
   page-break-after: always;
 }
 table.druha {
   margin: 50px 10px 0px 10px;
   padding-bottom: 50px;
   page-break-inside:auto;
 }    
 caption {
   text-align: left;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 13px;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
 }    
 th:first-child {
   width: 250px;
   padding: 3px 6px;
 }    
 th:last-child {
   width: 200px;
   padding: 3px 3px;
 }    
 th {
   width: 200px;
   padding: 3px 6px;
 }    
 tr {
   background: #f7fafa;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-weight: 400;
   page-break-inside:avoid;
   page-break-after:auto;
 }    
 td:first-child {
   text-align: justify;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style: normal;
 }    
 td:last-child {
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 12px;
 }    
 td {
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-align: center;
 }    
 #maly {
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 10px;
 }
```